# C# Named Pipes, how to detect a client disconnecting

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

My current named pipe implementation reads like this:

```
while (true)
{
  byte[] data = new byte[256];                        
  int amount = pipe.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
  if (amount <= 0)
  {
      // i was expecting it to go here when a client disconnects but it doesnt
     break;
  }
  // do relevant stuff with the data
}
```

how can I correctly detect when a client disconnects?

Answer (score 3):

Set a read timeout and poll the `NamedPipeClientStream.IsConnected` flag when a timeout occurs.

A Read Timeout will cause reads that are idle for the timeout duration to throw `InvalidOperationException`

If you are not reading, and want to detect disconnections, call this method on a worker thread for the lifetime of your pipe connection.

```
while(pipe.IsConnected && !isPipeStopped) //use a flag so that you can manually stop this thread
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Current.Sleep(500);
}

if(!pipe.IsConnected)
{
    //pipe disconnected
    NotifyOfDisconnect();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what if i dont read from the pipe for a duration longer than this timeout on purpose? my pipe is idle for most of the time.

Comment: I suggest a worker thread that polls IsConnected for the lifetime of your pipe. Perhaps wrap it all up in a dedicated class. Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to tell if your pipe has been broken (remotely) is to always use asynchronous reads instead of sync ones, and to always have at least one read submitted asynchronously. That is, for every successful read you get, post another async read, whether you intend to read another or not. If you close the pipe, or the remote end closes it, you'll see the async read complete, but with a null read size. You can use this to detect a pipe disconnection. Unfortunately, the pipe will still show IsConnected, and you still need to manually close it, I think, but it does allow you to detect when something went wonky.

Comment: I would not use a timer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WaitForPipeDrain()` method **after** Writing to the Pipe (using `WriteByte()` or `Write()`) and catch the exception which is "Pipe is Broken".

You may want to put that in a `while` loop and keep writing to the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

in the case of Synchronous call you track the -1 return by ReadByte of Stream abstract class, which is inherited by NamedPipeServerStream:

```
        var _pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeConst._PIPE_NAME, PipeDirection.InOut);
        int firstByte = _pipeServer.ReadByte();
        const int END_OF_STREAM = -1;
        if (firstByte == END_OF_STREAM)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

The docs states indeed:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Reads a byte from a pipe.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The byte, cast to System.Int32, or -1 indicates the end of the stream (the pipe
    //     has been closed).
    public override int ReadByte();
```

Only after a first failed read your IsConnected property will be correctly set to false:

```
_pipeServer.IsConnected
```

You might observe that even on the
[official illustration of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) (and more precisely in the StreamString class)
this check is not done:

Do not forget to **Vote** for this answer and visit my [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVww4lxZnKGx_5I4clpb52w). More info on my profile.

Regards !